# how insert foreach function in html?

Tags: php, html

I'm a newbie who's been looking for a solution regarding inserting a PHP foreach output in HTML,

there is my query code:

```
$qr = $this->db->query("select journalDetail.COA_CODE, COA_TITLE, COA_TYPE from t_journal_detail journalDetail left join r_coa coaTitle on journalDetail.coa_code=coaTitle.coa_code where journalDetail.JOURNAL_ID = '".$journalId."'");
$coaTitle = $qr->result_array();

    foreach ($coaTitle as $coa) {
        echo '<td width=55><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:left>'.$coaTitle[0]['COA_CODE'].'</span></td><br>';
    }
```

and there is my html code:

```
$detailJournal = '<!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                            <table> 
                                <tr>            
                            <table border = 0 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 0 align = center>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width=55><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:left>'.$coaTitle[0]['COA_CODE'].'</span></td>
                                    <td width=170><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:center>'.$coaTitle[0]['COA_TITLE'].'</span></td>
                                    <td width=55><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:center>IDR</span></td>
                                    <td width=81><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:right>'.$journalDetail[0]['ORIG'].'</span></td>
                                    <td width=89><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:right>0</span></td>
                                    <td width=89><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:right>'.$journalDetail[0]['SUM'].'</span></td>
                                </tr><br><br>        
                            </table>
                        </html>';

    return $detailJournal;

}
```

the question is how insert foreach in html?

Comment: give the full html code. You already insert an output inside foreach loop.

Comment: The easiest way would be by not putting the HTML in a PHP variable but to end the PHP block (`?>`), write your html (with any PHP you need, like usual), and then start the PHP block again. Otherwise, you need to concatenate your variable.

Comment: i try insert php block ( ?> ) but it's not working, i try insert function in model it's not working too

Comment: What have you tried? What are you looking for - what is not working with the given code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach`, rather than `echo`ing the value, build it up into a string 
 (adding each part with `.=`) which you can then insert into your larger HTML...

```
$qr = $this->db->query("select journalDetail.COA_CODE, COA_TITLE, COA_TYPE from t_journal_detail journalDetail left join r_coa coaTitle on journalDetail.coa_code=coaTitle.coa_code where journalDetail.JOURNAL_ID = '".$journalId."'");
$coaTitle = $qr->result_array();
$htmlTable = "";
foreach ($coaTitle as $coa) {
    $htmlTable .= '<tr>';
    $htmlTable .= '<td width=55><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:left>'.$coa['COA_CODE'].'</span></td><br>';

    //  Continue adding fields using `$coa['FIELD NAME']` and $htmlTable .= ...

    $htmlTable .= '</tr>';
}

$detailJournal = '<!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                            <table> 
                                <tr>            
                            <table border = 0 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 0 align = center>'
                              .$htmlTable.'<br><br>        
                            </table>
                        </html>';

    return $detailJournal;

}
```

You just need to use the line

```
$htmlTable .= '<td width=55><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:left>'.$coa['COA_CODE'].'</span></td><br>';
```

as a template to add in the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$qr = $this->db->query("select journalDetail.COA_CODE, COA_TITLE, COA_TYPE from t_journal_detail journalDetail left join r_coa coaTitle on journalDetail.coa_code=coaTitle.coa_code where journalDetail.JOURNAL_ID = '".$journalId."'");
$coaTitle = $qr->result_array();

    foreach ($coaTitle as $coa) {
        echo '<td width=55><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:left>'.$coa[0]['COA_CODE'].'</span></td><br>';
    }
```

**in foreach($coaTitle as $coa) you must use *$coa* instead $*coaTitle***

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add php code in html file then, you can add directly by adding  php tag, and save file with **.php** extension

```
$detailJournal = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <table> 
        <tr>            
            <table border = 0 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 0 align = center>
                <?php
                foreach ($coaTitle as $coa) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=55><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:left>'.$coa['COA_CODE'].'</span></td>
                        <td width=170><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:center>'.$coa[0]['COA_TITLE'].'</span></td>
                        <td width=55><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:center>IDR</span></td>
                        <td width=81><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:right>'.$journalDetail[0]['ORIG'].'</span></td>
                        <td width=89><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:right>0</span></td>
                        <td width=89><span style=font-size:10pt; line-height:19px; text-align:right>'.$journalDetail[0]['SUM'].'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>  
            </table>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Additionally, are you sure that it does anything good? Why is there an opening `<?php` within the output?